# Pie Chart Value Labels Inside with Category Labels Outside - Pandas & xlxswriter

Tags: python, pandas, charts, label, pie-chart

I am using xlsxwriter and add_series to create and export a pie chart to Excel. I currently have it showing both the percentage label and category label on the outside of the chart.
Is it possible to have the percentage label on the inside and the category on the outside?

My current code is:

```
chart.add_series({'categories' : '=Pivots!B4:B9', "values" : "=Pivots!C4:C9", "data_labels" : {"percentage" : True, "category": True, "position" : 'outside_end'}})
```

Current Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I believe remove `"position" : 'outside_end'` or change it to `"position" : 'inside_end'`.

Comment: Is it possible to do that in Excel? I don't see any option that separates the data cable value and category like your second image.

Comment: It is possible in Excel. The bottom picture was created in Excel, however it does involve creating 2 data series and laying on top of each other.